# Simpler way to create special binary Lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create a List of binary arrays, which are combination of two inverse binary `Tuples`, like this:

```
tup3={{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
 {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
 {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
```

I was able to create it using `Riffle` and then reshaping the array (for arbitrary `nn`):

```
nn=3;
ArrayReshape[Riffle[Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]], {2^nn, 2*nn}]
```

However it looks too complicated to me, and I believe that *Mathematica* would provide a simpler method. Also I wonder whether there is a faster method.

---

**Edit:** Let me compare all methods up to now in terms of speed:
[image]

---

**Edit2 (01.01.2017, 23.00):**
For `nn=23`:

- SimonWoods2: 3.38987sec
- kglr5: 3.3****
- kglr4: 3.5703sec
- NicoDean: 6.63795sec
- SimonWoods1: 7.68363sec
- kglr3: 8.21169sec
- BobHanlon: 10.9597sec
- kglr2: 22.067sec
- kglr1: 22.9503sec

The methods of Simon Woods and kglr are significantly faster than my solution, and at the moment faster than any other proposals. And the top-3 for `nn=27`:

- kglr (`PadRight`): 63.13 +/- 2.86 sec (individual: 61.2264, 60.551, 63.6354, 67.7876, 62.4526)
- kglr (`ArrayPad`): 63.18 +/- 1.75 sec (individual: 63.54, 60.27, 63.57, 65.03, 63.50)
- Simon Woods (`ArrayFlatten`): 62.89 +/- 3.00 sec (individual: 58.5406, 63.3664, 64.3787, 65.2684)

(very similar and within the errors)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is faster:

```
ArrayFlatten[{{Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]}}]
```

This is slower, but as an alternative approach:

```
IntegerDigits[Range[2^nn] (2^nn - 1), 2, 2 nn]
```

Comment: Thanks, your first method is significantly faster than mine (and all other proposed ones). I was not aware of ``ArrayFlatten`` before, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. kglr's latest is very competitive, I would not be surprised to see faster methods appear. I suggest you let this question remain open for at least a day or two - these list manipulation performance optimisation questions tend to be very popular and often produce some interesting tricks and clever code.

Comment: I am surprised that `IntegerDigits` is so much slower here.  Any thought to why that is?

Comment: It's a bit faster if you expand out the `Range[]`: `With[{s = 2^nn}, IntegerDigits[Range[s - 1, s^2 - s, s - 1] , 2, 2 nn]]`, but still slower than `Tuples[]`. I also note that the first method yields a packed array, but the second one doesn't.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the `IntegerDigits` method produces an array which is unpacked at the top level, though I'm not sure if that accounts for the difference. I think maybe `Tuples` is just very very fast.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Alternatives using `ArrayPad` and `PadRight`:

```
(out1 = ArrayPad[Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], {{0}, {0, nn}}, Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]]); 
 // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.344810

```
(out1a = PadRight[Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], {2^nn, 2 nn}, Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]]);
 // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.315793

```
(out1b = ArrayReshape[Riffle[Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]], {2^nn, 2*nn}]);
 // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.687106

Simon's updated version is the fastest among the three methods:

```
(out1c = ArrayFlatten[{{Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]}}]); //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.259235

```
 out1 == out1a == out1b == out1c
```

> True

**Original Post:**

```
Join @@@ Transpose[{#, Reverse@#}] &@Tuples[{0, 1}, nn]
```

or

```
MapThread[Join, {#, Reverse@#} &@Tuples[{0, 1}, nn]]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1,
>      1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
>      {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}}

Note: both of these are much slower than OP's method.

```
ArrayReshape[Transpose@{#, Reverse@#} &@Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], {2^nn, 2*nn}]
```

is much faster but still not as fast as OP's approach.

Comment: Thank you kglr, this is certainly much simpler than my method, much more elegant (i didn't think of ``Join``). However, surprisingly, it is quite a bit slower than my method.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with a fresh kernel to keep caching from affecting the timings

```
f1[nn_] := f1[nn] =
  ArrayReshape[
   Riffle[Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]],
   {2^nn, 2*nn}]

f2[nn_] := f2[nn] =
  Flatten /@ Transpose[{Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]}]
```

Adding solution provided by @SimonWoods

```
f3[nn_] := f3[nn] =
  ArrayFlatten[{{Tuples[{0, 1}, nn], Tuples[{1, 0}, nn]}}]
```

Since the time grows exponentially, use [`ListLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogPlot.html)

```
ListLogPlot[
 Table[{
    AbsoluteTiming[f1[n]][[1]],
    AbsoluteTiming[f2[n]][[1]],
    AbsoluteTiming[f3[n]][[1]]}, {n, 24}] //
  Transpose,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLegends -> {f1, f2, f3}]
```

[image]

Solution provided by @SimonWoods performs best. Verifying that the functions are equivalent

```
And @@ Table[f1[n] === f2[n] === f3[n], {n, 24}]

(*  True  *)
```